# iPhone cancel button

Tags: iphone

I saw in the Facebook application for iPhone,on the login page that there is a cancel button which can stop the login operation done by the user. How can we build that type of cancel button?

thankz in advance

Comment: sory can not understand what you mean by built of cancel button.What functionality you want?

Comment: How about asking facebook about their problem rather than this uncomplete question here?

Comment: cancel button menz,if the user press the login button the login process occurs,but the user want to cancel this operation before complting the login by pressing a this cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), simply `[request cancel]` as the button action.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know is that facebook provides a login web form for all aplications you can't change it and it does have a cancel button build in.  If you want to provide your own implementation of the log in interface you need to register your app whit them,and it takes a while.